# Send xstate message through vue-kanban module

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, kanban, xstate

im struggling with the vue-kanban plugin, which includes xstate and dragula module.
https://github.com/BrockReece/vue-kanban

looking at the stateMachineConfig, which I get activate by adding this as a prop to the kanban component, somehow I should be possible to send messages like "RELINQUISH_TASK", which triggers the item to be moved back into the 'on-hold' column.

```
stateMachineConfig: {
  id: 'kanban',
  initial: 'on-hold',
  states: {
    'on-hold': {
      on: {
        PICK_UP: 'in-progress',
      },
    },
    'in-progress': {
      on: {
        RELINQUISH_TASK: 'on-hold',
        PUSH_TO_QA: 'needs-review',
      },
    },
    'needs-review': {
      on: {
        REQUEST_CHANGE: 'in-progress',
        PASS_QA: 'approved',
      },
    },
    approved: {
      type: 'final',
    },
  },
},
```

how can i trigger this message?

In the vue-kanban component, I can see that only the Machine gets imported, but not the send.

Any help would be appeciated.

thanks,
Adrian